unsigned charS and scanf in C
The input accepts numbers from 0 to 255, which must be stored in variables a and b, which are both unsigned char.
My code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a, b;
    int res = scanf("%hhu %hhu", &a, &b);
    printf("res = %d, a = %hhu, b = %hhu\n", res, a, b);
    return 0;
}
//input: 7 8
//output: res = 2, a = 0, b = 8

The problem is that the first variable is never assigned a value. It is always zero.
The most interesting thing is that if you change the char type to short, everything starts working. What's the problem?
I'm using Windows, MVC, gcc 9.2.0.
Examples, when it works:
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a = 5, b = 87;
    printf("a = %hhu, b = %hhu\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

//output: a = 5, b = 87

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short a, b;
    int res = scanf("%hu %hu", &a, &b);
    printf("res = %d, a = %hu, b = %hu\n", res, a, b);
    return 0;
}
//input: 82 64
//output: res = 2, a = 82, b = 64

And when this doesn't work:
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a, b;
    scanf("%hhu", &a);
    scanf("%hhu", &b);
    printf("a = %hu, b = %hu\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
//input: 8
//input: 7
//output: a = 0, b = 7


C and C++ are different languages. This looks like C so please remove the C++ tag. Also add the missing #include <stdio.h>.

Why aren't you using %hhu for the output as well? Especially considering that the variable values will be promoted to int, not unsigned int. Which means that the %u format is wrong.

Which environment (compiler etc.) do you use ? I cannot reproduce on Windows and VisualStudio (MSVC).

@Liliia D., With "if you change the char type to short, everything starts working" --> did the format "%hhu "%hhu" reamin.. If not what was used?  Best to post the code used.

This is undefined behavior - C18#7.21.6.1 - 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.286) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined. At the function call, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes special implicit conversions. Details on implicit conversion - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions

Are you certain the code you posted is the same as what you're running? Did you remember to save your source file before compiling?

@NateEldredge yes, its same. i turned on autosave toogle and before launching I wait until it saves

@chux i edited my post and added some info, can u check this?

I can't reproduce your bug with either MSVC or GCC (version 8.1.0 and 12.2.0)

The format specifiers in printf for unsigned char should still be %hhu, not %hu as in your last example.  That's almost certainly not the issue, but you should fix it, because some people will refuse to look any deeper into your issue as soon as they've spotted one thing that's not exactly right.

@CGi03 Also clang works  (16.0)

Maybe you could make a screen recording showing exactly what you are doing to build and run.  The code itself seems fine, and nobody else can reproduce your issue, so either it's something about the way you are building and running the program, or else it's a bug in your compiler or library; and it's not reasonable to consider the second possibility until the first is thoroughly ruled out.

thx all. i found the solution: I removed old gcc version (32x, gcc 9.2.0) and installed a new one (64x, gcc 14.2.0). maybe the problem was in 32/64.

@LiliiaD. Good you found the answer.  Tip for the future: be sure code posted has all needed #include and compiles cleanly with lots of warnings enabled.

@H.S. There's no UB if the types and the conversion specifiers match, which is the case here. The conversion specifiers take default argument promotions in account, which is one of the big reasons for using them so that we don't have to worry about promotion.

@Lundin Is it because of C11#6.3.1.1/2?

@H.S. No, it's the fprintf documentation in chapter 7 saying that if you use the correct conversion specifier then everything is fine. If the function knows what the original type was, it can know what to do with the potentially "default argument promoted" int. Which probably just means casting back the argument from the va_list to the type the programmer told *printf to use.

%hh was introduced with C99, whereas %h was always present since C89. The gcc/mingw Windows port suffered a long time from using the skunky Microsoft Visual Studio CRT library (MSVCRT), which didn't support standard C (C99 or later).
If throwing in #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1 before #include <stdio.h> magically solves the problem, then the problem is the CRT. Try it.
Newer versions of Mingw use a newer Microsoft CRT "Universal C Runtime" (UCRT), which does support most of standard C. If building the compiler together with this lib, all problems should go away - which is likely why installing a new compiler accidentally solved the problem for you.
You can find lots of builds with the new CRT from https://winlibs.com/. The official Sourceforge links for Mingw are poorly maintained.
